Polkit agents for headless/login-less sessions
I currently have a Qt5 desktop-app on Debian kiosk (polkit 105) that I deliver as a user-interface.  Occasionally, an admin may walk by and need to run a privileged task, and so I use:
execve(
   "/usr/bin/pkexec", 
   [ "/usr/bin/slm-clean" ],
   ...
);

That invokes gnome-polkit-agent which authenticates the user according to the following policy found in /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.slm.policy :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>
  <action id="org.sim.slm.slm-clean">
    <description>Clear SLM</description>
    <message>Authentication is required to clear the SLM. This may destroy any SLM processes that are currently running.</message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/slm-clean</annotate>
  </action>
</policyconfig>

I'd like to consider moving this away from a desktop-app and towards a web-app on a headless server.  I've written an HTTP server which can serve static files, and implement dynamic API routes.
I can easily intercept the POST /api/slm-clean route, and call execve, but what do I do about the polkit-agent?  The user isn't in a gnome-session, and the textual fallback wont be of any help here either.
Here are a couple of ideas:

Link to libpolkit-agent-1.0 and register my backend as a polkit agent, then handle any authentication requests by comparing some token found in the POST body.

Abandon polkit entirely and give the script a setuid bit (chmod u+s /usr/bin/slm-clean), then move any authentication/messaging to the web-server.

Authenticate users through PAM, and then instead of pkexec, I can run /usr/bin/slm-clean with the UID of the authenticated user.  I really don't know what I'd be doing here.


I know red-hat's cockpit must have solved this somehow as it serves a systemd front-end over a web-server and must do authentications.  I can also confirm that cockpit doesn't intercept or interfere with gnome-polkit-agent if I run it on the same machine as a gnome-session.
